# cURL error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed

Tags: php, curl, travis-ci, gnutls

I am running into the following error from a PHP component that uses CURL to request a URI via SSL:

```
cURL error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

This error occurs in the travis-ci.org environment, but not in any of our test environments. See travis-ci build [144663700](https://travis-ci.org/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/jobs/144663700).

I have found out that the PHP version running in the Travis worker is compiled again "GnuTLS/2.12.14" on "Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS" or with "GnuTLS/2.12.23" on "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS".

In our development environments, we use standard packages compiled against "OpenSSL/1.0.1t" on Debian (various versions).

Therefore, I assume the problem is related to "GnuTLS/2.12.14" or "GnuTLS/2.12.23", or the parameters with which they have been compiled.

I have tried limiting the SSL versions with the CURL constant CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, but that does not solve the problem.

According to www.ssllabs.com the host in question - api.reporting.cloud - supports TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0.

Would anyone have any hints or pointers for me?

Answer (score 8):

A workaround to this problem is to configure travis-ci to use the standard Ubuntu Trusty php5-cli and php5-curl packages. The standard packages offer the CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 constant.

The .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
sudo: required

dist: trusty

language: php

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -y install git zip php5-cli php5-curl

before_script:
  - php -r "printf('PHP %s', phpversion());"
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction

script:
  - mkdir -p ./build/logs
  - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

In the PHP source, it is then simply a matter of setting the aforementioned constant in the case of the PHP code being executed by travis-ci:

```
if (getenv('TRAVIS')) {
    $options['curl'][CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1;
}
```

This workaround has the disadvantage that it only works on the specific PHP version that Ubuntu Trusty offers (PHP 5.5). Considering PHP 5.5 reached end of life on July 10, 2016, this solution is not acceptable.

It would be ideal for travis-ci to update to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but Brandon Burton, Infrastructure Manager at travis-ci [wrote](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5659) on February 28, 2016:

> Given that, we are currently focused on support 12.04 and 14.04 as our
>   primary environments. At the moment, it is unlikely that we'll be
>   supporting 16.04 as a native environment this year.

Therefore, it would seem we are stuck with Ubuntu Trusty for a while.

The root of this problem is that the PHP version that runs on travis-ci was compiled with gnutls-cli (GnuTLS) 2.12.23, from 2011. This specific version of gnutls-cli has problems with some (but not all) TLS 1.2 connections.

@travis-ci: Would it be possible to re-compile the PHP versions you use against a more modern version of GnuTLS -- or at least one that better supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: unfortunately Ubuntu 16.04 is also plagued by this problem.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, it is possible to control the SSL protocol that curl uses with the CURL_SSLVERSION_* constants.

By setting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1);
```

I can force curl to use "TLS 1.1".

By setting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

I can force curl to use "TLS 1.0".

To test all possible SSL protocols, I created the following script, which is then executed by travis-ci:

```
<?php

$sslVersions = [
    CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2,
    CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3,
];

var_dump(curl_version());

foreach ($sslVersions as $sslVersion) {

    $uri = "https://api.reporting.cloud";

    printf("Trying %d", $sslVersion);
    echo PHP_EOL;

    $ch = curl_init($uri);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE        , true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        , 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     , $sslVersion);

    if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

}

exit(1);
```

The output of this script in my development environments is:

```
array(9) {
  ["version_number"]=>
  int(468480)
  ["age"]=>
  int(3)
  ["features"]=>
  int(182173)
  ["ssl_version_number"]=>
  int(0)
  ["version"]=>
  string(6) "7.38.0"
  ["host"]=>
  string(19) "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
  ["ssl_version"]=>
  string(14) "OpenSSL/1.0.1t"
  ["libz_version"]=>
  string(5) "1.2.8"
  ["protocols"]=>
  array(21) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "dict"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "file"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "ftps"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "gopher"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "http"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "https"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "imap"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "imaps"
    [9]=>
    string(4) "ldap"
    [10]=>
    string(5) "ldaps"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "pop3"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "pop3s"
    [13]=>
    string(4) "rtmp"
    [14]=>
    string(4) "rtsp"
    [15]=>
    string(3) "scp"
    [16]=>
    string(4) "sftp"
    [17]=>
    string(4) "smtp"
    [18]=>
    string(5) "smtps"
    [19]=>
    string(6) "telnet"
    [20]=>
    string(4) "tftp"
  }
}
Trying 0
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=HRB 25927; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=DE; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=DE; postalCode=28215; ST=Bremen; L=Bremen; street=Admiralstr. 54; O=Text Control GmbH; OU=ReportingCloud; OU=COMODO EV SSL; CN=api.reporting.cloud
*    start date: 2016-06-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-17 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.reporting.cloud matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reporting.cloud
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 14:22:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 952
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.reporting.cloud left intact


Trying 1
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=HRB 25927; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=DE; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=DE; postalCode=28215; ST=Bremen; L=Bremen; street=Admiralstr. 54; O=Text Control GmbH; OU=ReportingCloud; OU=COMODO EV SSL; CN=api.reporting.cloud
*    start date: 2016-06-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-17 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.reporting.cloud matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reporting.cloud
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 14:22:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 952
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.reporting.cloud left intact


Trying 4
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=HRB 25927; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=DE; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=DE; postalCode=28215; ST=Bremen; L=Bremen; street=Admiralstr. 54; O=Text Control GmbH; OU=ReportingCloud; OU=COMODO EV SSL; CN=api.reporting.cloud
*    start date: 2016-06-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-17 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.reporting.cloud matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reporting.cloud
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 14:22:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 952
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.reporting.cloud left intact


Trying 5
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.1 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=HRB 25927; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=DE; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=DE; postalCode=28215; ST=Bremen; L=Bremen; street=Admiralstr. 54; O=Text Control GmbH; OU=ReportingCloud; OU=COMODO EV SSL; CN=api.reporting.cloud
*    start date: 2016-06-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-17 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.reporting.cloud matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reporting.cloud
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 14:22:41 GMT
< Content-Length: 952
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.reporting.cloud left intact


Trying 6
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=HRB 25927; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=DE; businessCategory=Private Organization; C=DE; postalCode=28215; ST=Bremen; L=Bremen; street=Admiralstr. 54; O=Text Control GmbH; OU=ReportingCloud; OU=COMODO EV SSL; CN=api.reporting.cloud
*    start date: 2016-06-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-06-17 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.reporting.cloud matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reporting.cloud
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.5 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 14:22:41 GMT
< Content-Length: 952
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.reporting.cloud left intact


Trying 2
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support
* Closing connection 0
string(39) "OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support"


Trying 3
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.reporting.cloud/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 40.76.93.116...
* Connected to api.reporting.cloud (40.76.93.116) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.reporting.cloud:443 
* Closing connection 0
string(68) "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.reporting.cloud:443 "
```

Here, we can clearly see that 'SSL connection using TLSv1.0' is connecting correctly to the backend server.

However, running the same script on travi-ci results in the following:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 7

Call Stack:
    0.0002     241400   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 8

Call Stack:
    0.0002     241400   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2' in /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php on line 9

Call Stack:
    0.0002     241400   1. {main}() /home/travis/build/TextControl/txtextcontrol-reportingcloud-php/demo/ssl-issue.php:0

array(9) {
  'version_number' =>
  int(464384)
  'age' =>
  int(3)
  'features' =>
  int(50749)
  'ssl_version_number' =>
  int(0)
  'version' =>
  string(6) "7.22.0"
  'host' =>
  string(19) "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
  'ssl_version' =>
  string(14) "GnuTLS/2.12.14"
  'libz_version' =>
  string(7) "1.2.3.4"
  'protocols' =>
  array(18) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "dict"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "file"
    [2] =>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [3] =>
    string(4) "ftps"
    [4] =>
    string(6) "gopher"
    [5] =>
    string(4) "http"
    [6] =>
    string(5) "https"
    [7] =>
    string(4) "imap"
    [8] =>
    string(5) "imaps"
    [9] =>
    string(4) "ldap"
    [10] =>
    string(4) "pop3"
    [11] =>
    string(5) "pop3s"
    [12] =>
    string(4) "rtmp"
    [13] =>
    string(4) "rtsp"
    [14] =>
    string(4) "smtp"
    [15] =>
    string(5) "smtps"
    [16] =>
    string(6) "telnet"
    [17] =>
    string(4) "tftp"
  }
}
Trying 0
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."


Trying 1
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."


Trying 0
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."


Trying 0
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."


Trying 0
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."


Trying 2
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* GnuTLS does not support SSLv2
* Closing connection #0
string(29) "GnuTLS does not support SSLv2"


Trying 3
* About to connect() to api.reporting.cloud port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 40.76.93.116... * connected
* found 164 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
* Closing connection #0
string(76) "gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received."
```

I also noticed that the constants CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 and CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 are not available on travis-ci's PHP 5.6, nor PHP 7 versions.

To summarize, I have looped through all possible CURL_SSLVERSION_* constants and not one single one allows me to connect to api.reporting.cloud on travis-ci, regardless of which PHP version I use.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can connect to api.reporting.cloud from travis-ci?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to the problem in this [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnutls-help%40lists.gnutls.org/msg00688.html):

> The server doesn't like something in the TLS 1.2 support of gnutls
>   2.12 since if you disable it, it seems to work. The same server works with gnutls 3.2 and the only difference in the client hello of the two
>   versions is that gnutls 3.2 has more features enabled.

I am using (required to use) "gnutls-cli (GnuTLS) 2.12.23".

The following returns the aforementioned error:

```
gnutls-cli --priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.2" api.reporting.cloud
```

Yet, forcing "TLS 1.1" or "TLS 1.0", returns as expected:

```
gnutls-cli --priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.1" api.reporting.cloud
gnutls-cli --priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.0" api.reporting.cloud
```

The next step is to make this setting from PHP via CURL (in specific case of faulty library version).